# C# Error CS1503

Tags: c#

I can't get this code to work because of the error CS1503

```cs
public async Task InstallCommand ;
{
    client.MessageReceived += HandleCommand;
    await commands.AddModuleAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly) ;
}
```

Comment: You should start with some tutorials... Pay attention to the method declaration and character literal topics. :)

Comment: Voting to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method declaration, change `;` to `()`

```cs
public async Task InstallCommand()
{
    client.MessageReceived += HandleCommand;
    await commands.AddModuleAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly);
}
```